# How to inject CSS in Gecko WebBrowser Control

Tags: c#, css, gecko

This works on web browser control, but cant apply same on gecko

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument) as IHTMLDocument2;
IHTMLStyleSheet ss = doc.createStyleSheet("", 0);
ss.cssText = @".navSub_top, .navSub_middle, .navSub_bottom { display: none; };";
```

Can you please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain GeckoStyleSheet with the following code:

```
var stylesheet = browser.Document.StyleSheets.First(x => x.Href.EndsWith("SomeStylesheetName.css"));
```

Now, having the stylesheet, you can access a CssRules collection and add new rule:

```
stylesheet.CssRules.Add(@".navSub_top, .navSub_middle, .navSub_bottom { display: none; };");
```

Or edit existing rule by accessing them and using e.g. StyleCssText

[image]